# pyautogui how to locate image, move to top left of image and then move relative

Tags: python, pyautogui

[image]

I'm able to locate the image 'ScheduledBy.png' boxed in black
and I can move the mouse the relative distance, but I don't know how to get the mouse to move to the top left of the image first.

Currently when I run it just moves the mouse relative where it's already located

```
from pyautogui import *

import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random  
import win32api, win32con

    
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ScheduledBy.png', confidence=0.9) !=None:
    # need to move x277 y25 relative to top left of 'ScheduledBy.png'
    pyautogui.moveRel(277,25)
    time.sleep(.1)
    pyautogui.click()
    
    
else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

```
from pyautogui import *

import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random  
import win32api, win32con

    
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ScheduledBy.png', confidence=0.9) !=None:
    pyautogui.moveTo('ScheduledBy.png')
    # need to move x277 y25 relative to top left of 'ScheduledBy.png'
    pyautogui.moveRel(277,25)
    time.sleep(.1)
    pyautogui.click()
    
    
else:
    print("No")
```